# How to Logout in a JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, primefaces

**I have to use my Company login resource** and, how can I set the logout servlet into my primefaces component?

How "translate" this...

```
//in a jsp page:
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/servlet/com.app.ServletEndSession?initialPage=/index.jsp" > Logout </a>
```

...into this:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" action="??" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<a/>` should become

```
<p:button href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/servlet/com.app.ServletEndSession?initialPage=/index.jsp" value="Dialogit"/>
```

Comment: kolossus, that is exactly what I want. Thank you! I've just exchanged the **requestContextPath** by **requestContentType**, because it was duplicating **myAppContext** as the following: https://mySite.com/myAppContext/myAppContext/servlet/com.app.ServletEndSession?initialPage=/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a managed bean on the commandButton and then do a redirect in your page?
As you definitely want to navigate away with p:commandbutton youw would want to set ajax="false"  put action .

Alternatively you could just use

```
<p:commandButton type="button" value="logout" onclick="javascriptTolinkToServletEndEsssion" />
```